# Simple execution sequence for real time systems drawn in Java

Tags: java, scheduling, plot, real-time-systems

I need to draw some execution sequences for some real time systems scheduled using rate monotonic algorithm. The drawing has to be done using Java and it has to be very basic.
Do you a very simple way to do this drawing? Simpler than Graphics2D?

Thanks a lot!

The diagram I want to be as simple or even simpler as this one:[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'draw', what are the requirements? Does it have to be graphical, or can it be primarily text?

Comment: I edited the question and now you can see what I wanted to say. thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try with **Processing**, which is able to do such things with Java in zero time.. home page [here](http://processing.org/).

You can easily embed a Processing frame inside your app, but remember that they are based on AWT so they are heavy weight and don't like being overlayed (for example in a `JInternalFrame`)

By the way what you seem to want to draw is a Gantt chart right?

You can try with JFreeChart too (see demo [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartGanttDemo1.htm)), it's quite customizable and works fine.. homepage [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Comment: Thanks, I've looked over it and I was impressed. But I don't need an applet (and Processing uses applets as far as I saw), I don't have to show the diagram during the execution of the program. I just need to save the diagram in an image. That's all I want

Comment: Processing is able to export its content in various formats (PDF or images) and it's possible to embed a single frame inside your app as you wish without being an applet (it's completely in Java so there are no problems)

Comment: Hello again, it's not a Gantt chart, but it has the similarity that each task in time is represented on a line